# How to ask different set of work because of no support

Tags: new-job, software-development

I am in my probation period and I was hired as mid-level developer. While I have been doing a good job as mentioned in my one-to-one with my manager, recently I have hit a snag. There are two problems here.

The first problem was estimation. When I was onboarding, I was shown how to put in estimated hours.  Later when I started on that piece of work, the estimated hours shown vs. the work were inverse of each other, and the person who was showing me how to do estimations wasn't a developer so the estimation was hugely flawed.

Now that I have hit a certain milestone, I have hit issues where I need support.  My peer who I have been told to get help from is always busy and excuses himself.  This has made my work go way beyond my estimates.

How do I convey it to my senior that I am not getting help that I need which will affect my probation, and request different work without looking bad or making my peer look bad?

Comment: Do you have daily stand-ups? Not having access to the information you need is something to list as a "blocker".

Comment: @BittermanAndy yes we do but how can this be a blocker?

Comment: A blocker is anything which prevents you from completing a task.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I fear adversity, e.g. "why he called my name that he was unable to do a task coz I am not helping him" and might be a problem with me in future.

Comment: It seems you have an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/) here - your issue is not "how to ask for a different set of work", it is "how to professionally indicate that you are not getting the support you need".

Comment: Is it his duty to help you, or is he just helping you as a friend? If he has a duty to help you, don't hesitate in telling your boss that he's not helping.

Comment: @androidguy it is his duty, I was told to lean most on those peers to help but seem like the task they are given vs what I have been told are opposite which affect my timelines a lot, putting me under stress and anxiety to join stand up to repeating that "I am on x ticket for 3 weeks".

Comment: "Yesterday I did X, for the third week in a row. Today I will still be doing X, as best I can, but I am not confident of completing it. I am blocked from completing X because the information I have been requesting for the last three weeks has still not been provided to me." That's literally what the stand-up is for. Then the manager / Scrum Master / team collectively / whoever can prioritise people to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this phenomenon in a company when it's difficult to find important knowledge?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168890/what-is-this-phenomenon-in-a-company-when-its-difficult-to-find-important-knowl)

Answer (score 10):

Following on from some of your comments:

> I fear adversity, e.g. "why he called my name that he was unable to do a task coz I am not helping him" and might be a problem with me in future.

> I was told to lean most on those peers to help but seem like the task they are given vs what I have been told are opposite which affect my timelines a lot, putting me under stress and anxiety to join stand up to repeating that "I am on x ticket for 3 weeks"

Your problem here is *not* "how to ask different set of work because of no support" but "how to communicate that you are blocked". If you don't want to call individuals out by name, there are at least two options:

1. Something like "I need help from another member of the team here, who would be available to pair with me?"
2. Bring the issue up in private with your scrum master / manager / team lead.

You should absolutely never be turning up to a stand up and just saying "I've made no progress" for three weeks - although if you are, your scrum master / manager / team lead is also failing to do their job as one of the primary purposes of a stand up is to ensure any blockers are visible and resolved.

Comment: My experience with developers who don't understand what standups are for is that they say "I'm still working on X" for three weeks, without ever mentioning that they haven't actually made progress because they "don't want to look bad".

Comment: @DJClayworth Yep. But after the 3rd (arguably 2nd) day when a developer just says that, it's the job of the "scrum master" or whoever to inquire deeper - which is why I say they're not doing their job.

Comment: I don't disagree with you there.